# Show filtered result in textbox

Tags: powerapps

I am looking to display filtered result in text box. with the below script I am able to show the result in dropdown. Kindly assist in getting the same result in text box.

```
Filter(Gallery1.AllItems, Dropdown1.Selected.Value = Model).'Item'
```

This script works when its a dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dropdown can display a list of values, while a text box can only display a single value. In your case, you can use a function such as [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-concatenate) to concatenate the results into a single text value, as shown in the example below:

```
Concat(
    Filter(Gallery1.AllItems, Dropdown1.Selected.Value = Model),
    Item,
    ", ")
```

Comment: Suggested filter works, Thanks!